# The v-model does not seems to be updating

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm fairly new to vue so I'm sure this is just a dumb mistake on my part...

I am using vue 3 with `vue-class-component` and typescript.

I have a component that is essentially a wrapper for a `<textarea>`. It will eventually be a lightweight code editing component but for now, I'm just adding a "copy" button to it. Here is the relevant code:

*ToolTextArea.vue*

```html
<template>
  <div class="form-element">
    <label :for="id">{{ label }}</label>
    <div class="positional-container">
      <div class="toolbar">
        <button @click="copy" class="copy-button">copy</button>
      </div>
      <div class="textarea-container">
        <textarea
          autocapitalize="false"
          autocomplete="false"
          spellcheck="false"
          :class="cssClasses"
          :id="id"
          data-gramm="false"
          data-gramm_editor="false"
          data-enable-grammarly="false"
          :value="value"
          @input="handleChange"
          @keydown="handleKeydownEvent"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

*ToolTextarea.ts*

```js
import { Options, Vue, prop } from "vue-class-component";

...

class Props {
  label = prop<string>({ type: String, required: true });
  id = prop<string>({ type: String, required: true });
  value = prop<string>({ type: String, required: false, default: "" });
  textareaCssClass = prop<string>({
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: "",
  });
  showCopyButton = prop<boolean>({
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
    default: true,
  });
}

@Options({})
export default class ToolTextarea extends Vue.with(Props) {

...

handleChange(event: Event) {
  if (
      event &&
      event.target &&
      event.target instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement &&
      event.target.value
    ) {
      this.$emit("update:modelValue", event.target.value);
    }
  }

...

}
```

I then put a few of these components on another component. The point here is to create a UI for URL encoding/Decoding, but that's the important part. Here is the relevant code for that component:

*UrlEncoding.vue*

```html
<template>

...

  <ToolTextarea
    id="input"
    label="Unencoded"
    :value="input"
    textareaCssClass="tall"
    @update:modelValue="handleInputUpdate"
  />

...

  <button @click="encode">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
    Encode
  </button>
  <button @click="decode">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
    Decode
  </button>

...

  <ToolTextarea
    id="output"
    label="Encoded"
    :value="output"
    textareaCssClass="tall"
    @update:modelValue="handleOutputUpdate"
  />

</template>
```

*UrlEncodung.tx*

```js
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import ToolTextarea from "../ToolTextarea/ToolTextarea.vue";

@Options({
  components: {
    ToolTextarea,
  },
})
export default class UrlEncoding extends Vue {
  input = "";
  output = "";

...

  handleInputUpdate(event: string) {
    this.input = event;
  }

  handleOutputUpdate(event: string) {
    this.output = event;
  }

...

  encode() {
    console.log("this.input", this.input);
    console.log("this.output", this.output);
    let encoded = this.urlComponent
      ? encodeURIComponent(this.input)
      : encodeURI(this.input);

    ...

    this.output = encoded;
  }

  decode() {
    console.log("this.input", this.input);
    console.log("this.output", this.output);
    let decoded = this.urlComponent
      ? decodeURIComponent(this.output)
      : decodeURI(this.output);

    ...

    this.input = decoded;
  }
}
```

Ok, now that all the code is out there, here's the actual issue I am having.

When I type a value in the input (Unencoded) field and click the "Encode" button, the code runs as expected and the url encoded value is displayed in the output (Encoded) field. Great!

However, if I delete the content from the input field, and click the "Decode" button, I would expect the decoded value to be displayed in the input field, but it does not.

If I were to modify the output field in some way, say, ad a space to the end, then click the decode button, it works just fine.

I guess I just don't understand the model state in vue very well. This is going to be a super lightweight app and I don't want to use a heavy state manager. I also want to keep this as close to native JS as possible.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: `v-model="thing"` is a shorthand for `:modelValue="thing" @update:modelValue="v => thing = v"`.

Comment: So you need a `modelValue` prop to use this 2-way binding

Comment: I recommend outputting values with `{{thing}}`, or even `{{{thing}}}` (i.e. `{{ ( {thing: thing} ) }}`) to check them during development